# I want proper code to consume same Kafka topic by all the 3 instances of my application JAVA

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to consume same topic by all my instances.
i am using spring as following in my all instances it is same code.

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = Constants.MY_TOPIC, groupId = Constants.GROUP_NAME)
    public void consume(ConsfigData configData) {
        try {
            myservice.setConfig(configData, null);
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
```

am using the above code to consume the message.
But with above code it is not consume by all the instances it is consume by only one instances.

Answer (score 0):

When your instances share one consumer group, then messages will not be delivered to all instances. Kafka doesn't offer such a feature while using consumer groups

Comment: thanks for the information can i go without consumer group if possible how should i go.

Comment: Remove the groupId parameters, for a start. However, it's not clear why you want all instances to consume the same messages. That would cause duplicate processing, which isn't really what kafka consumers are meant to do

Comment: when I remove group_id from @KafkaListener am getting exception i.e.

Comment: [main] ERROR (SpringApplication.java:843) - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No group.id found in consumer config, container properties, or @KafkaListener annotation; a group.id is required when group management is used.
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]

Comment: You'll also need to disable group management, as the error says. I don't use spring-kafka to know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

set group name from application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=my-group-id

//ServiceListner
@KafkaListener(topics = Constants.MY_TOPIC )
public void consume(String config){
    try {
        configService.add(config);
    } catch (Exception e){
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```